# What nucleophilic reaction takes place in case of bad leaving group as well as 1* alpha carbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, carbocation, rearrangements

If we add HI to a substrate **Ph-C-C-OH** what will be the major product and what reaction mechn. will be followed?

My attempt: as -OH is bad Leaving Group, we cannot just simply proceed with Sn2 and remove the OH.
So first H2O (due to the H+ and lone pair on O) will form and then it will leave the substrate and then 1-2 hydride shift in **Ph-C-C+** --> **Ph-(C+)-C** and we will add I- at the carbocation.

My dilemma is how can we even form a 1* carbocation (even if it can be stabilised by rearrangement )

Is my attempt valid? If not what would be the real mechanism and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reaction has been [studied](https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v54-132) and yields 2-phenylethyliodide (Ph-CH2-CH2-I) in around 90% yield. The authors postulate a symmetrical non-classical carbocation with involvement of the aromatic system.

Comment: Yes thank you.....(SNGP will take place)

Comment: Another possibility: a hydride ion half-shifts to float over the carbon-carbon bond of what is originally the $\ce{CH2CH2OH}$ group. This would also displace the water molecule and distribute the positive charge over both carbons.